# Fourier-Bessel series of $f(x)=x^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, fourier-series, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions

I'm trying to calculate the expansion of $f : [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^2$ in a Fourier-Bessel series of zeroth order. In that case let $J_0$ be the $0$-th order Bessel function and $\alpha_n$ its $n$-th zero. In that case the expansion is

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n J_{0,n}(x)$$

with $J_{0,n}(x)=J_0(\alpha_n x)$. Considering then the inner product $\langle,\rangle$ given by

$$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)xdx$$

we have the orthogonality relation for $J_{0,n}$ and $J_{0,m}$

$$\langle J_{0,n},J_{0,m}\rangle = \dfrac{1}{2}J_1^2(\alpha_n)\delta_{nm}.$$

In that case the coefficients $c_n$ are given by

$$c_n = \dfrac{\langle f,J_{0,n}\rangle}{\langle J_{0,n},J_{0,n}\rangle}=\dfrac{2}{J_1^2(\alpha_n)}\int_0^1 f(x)J_0(\alpha_n x)xdx.$$

To compute this integral for $f(x)=x^2$ I did the following: first I've changed variables in the integral, using $u=\alpha_n x$ and $du=\alpha_n dx$ so that

$$\int_0^1 f(x)J_0(\alpha_n x)xdx = \int_0^{1}x^3J_0(\alpha_n x)dx = \dfrac{1}{\alpha_n^4}\int_0^{\alpha_n} u^3 J_0(u)du.$$

After that I've used the definition of $J_0$:

$$J_0(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(k+1)}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^{2k},$$

so that we have

$$\langle f,J_{0,n}\rangle =\dfrac{1}{\alpha_n^4}\int_0^{\alpha_n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(k+1)}\dfrac{u^{2k+3}}{2^{2k}}du$$

$$\langle f,J_{0,n}\rangle=\dfrac{1}{\alpha_n^4}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(k+1)}\dfrac{\alpha_n^{2k+4}}{2^{2k}(2k+4)}.$$

I know the answer is

$$c_n = \dfrac{2(\alpha_n^2-4)}{\alpha_n^3 J_1(\alpha_n)}$$

but I'm stuck there. How can I proceed this? Is there anything I did wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question seems linked to this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450256/expansion-coefficients-of-the-constant-function-for-bessel-series/4790248#4790248

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you instead try to integrate using the differential equation 
$$
x^2J_\nu''(x)+xJ_\nu'(x)+(x^2-\nu^2)J_\nu(x)=0
$$
and the recurrence formulas
$$
\frac{2\nu}{x}J_\nu(x)=J_{\nu-1}(x)+J_{\nu+1}(x)
\quad
\text{and}
\quad
2J'_\nu(x)=J_{\nu-1}(x)-J_{\nu+1}(x).
$$
I show you a first step, and you tell me if you need further steps.

Using the differential equation,
$$
\int x^3 J_0(x)\,dx=-\int x^3 J''_0(x)+x^2 J'_0(x)\,dx.
$$
Integrating the first term by parts,
$$
\int -x^3 J_0''(x)-x^2 J_0'(x)\,dx=-x^3J_0'(x)+2\int x^2 J_0'(x)\,dx
$$
Replacing $J_0'(x)=-J_1(x)$, we get
$$
\int x^3 J_0(x)\,dx=x^3J_1(x)+2\int x^2 J_0'(x)\,dx
$$
Working with the second integral, you should in the end get
$$
\int x^3 J_0(x)\,dx = (x^3 -4x)J_1(x)+2x^2 J_0(x)+C.
$$
It is a good exercise which I leave to you.

Comment: "When you say, you should get in the end," I am not even sure I understand what you mean. In the end, one wishes for the expansion coefficients such that $$x^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n\,J_n(x) . $$  Your final answer does not seem to answer the question. Please consider editing your solution and making the matter more patent.

Comment: I don't remember. Maybe I screwed up, or maybe the question was edited. ‍♂️