# Expansion coefficients of the constant function for bessel series.

Tags: special-functions, fourier-series, bessel-functions

**Question**

What are coefficients of the Fourier-Bessel  expansion of the constant function 1?

**My Solution**

Define $J_n:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ as the $n$'th order Bessel  function of the first kind.  Define $\alpha_i\in \mathbb{R}^+$ as the $i$'th positive root of $J_0$.

Let
$$z_i = \int_{r = 0}^1 J_0(\alpha_i r) r\, \mathrm{d} r.$$  Mathematica says that

$$z_i = \frac{J_1(\alpha_i)}{\alpha_i}.$$  Is this as close to "closed form" as I can get?

I have looked in the Wolfram functions [page](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/) for identities of this type but nothing seemed to fit the bill.  Any ideas?

Comment: How much nicer of an expression could you want? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the identities

$$\begin{align}
xJ_0(x)&=xJ_1'(x)+J_1(x) \tag 1\\\\
J_0'(x)&=-J_1(x) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Then, we have from $(1)$ and $(2)$

$$xJ_0(x)=\left(xJ_1(x)\right)' \tag 3$$

Using $(3)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1J_0(ar)\,r\,dr&=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^1\frac{d\,\left(rJ_1(ar)\right)}{dr}\,dr\\\\
&=\frac{1}{a}J_1(a)
\end{align}$$

Letting $a=\alpha_i$ recovers the result sought in the OP.

---

As requested in comment, the evaluation of the integral

$$J_1^2(\alpha_i)=2\int_0^1J_0^2(\alpha_ir)d\,dr$$

is easily facilitated by the identity

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac12 x^2 \left(J_0^2(x)+J_1^2(x)\right)\right)=xJ_0^2(x) $$

and the fact the $J_0(\alpha_i)=0$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but this isn't exactly what I was looking for.  I am interested in something like $J_1(\alpha_i)/\alpha_i = X$, where $X$ is somewhat closer to a closed form that $J_1(\alpha_i)/\alpha_i$.  Does that make sense?  I have been fooling around and I think that I have $$J_1(\alpha_i)^2 = 2 \int_{r=0}^1 J_0(\alpha_i r)^2 r \mathrm{d}r$$ Do you know where that could have come from?

Comment: I don't see a need to delete it.  It is still useful and true.  I don't know if someone else will down-vote it thought, I won't.

Comment: @fred Sure. I've added.  Please let me know how else I can help.

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**

My answer roughly follows what is written by Mark Viola. I have put the solution in a form that I find more systematic and include a bibliography. I have undertaken to write this solution in order to solve what I hope is a related problem (cf, [2]). For good measure, I have posted my solution.

**Solution**

The generating function of the Bessel functions of the first kind for integral order may be used to show [1] that
$$
J_{-n}(x)  = (-1)^n\,J_n(x) \qquad (\text{integral}~n). \tag{10}
$$

Further, the functions $J_α$   satisfy the  recurrence relation
$$\frac{2\alpha}{x} J_\alpha(x) = J_{\alpha-1}(x) + J_{\alpha+1}(x)
\tag{20}
$$
and
$$
2\frac{dJ_\alpha (x)}{dx} = J_{\alpha-1}(x) - J_{\alpha+1}(x).
\tag{30}
$$
These two identities are often combined, e.g. added or subtracted, to yield various other relations. For example, adding these yields
$$\frac{2\alpha}{x} J_\alpha(x) + 2\frac{dJ_\alpha (x)}{dx} = 2\,J_{\alpha-1}(x)   
\tag{40}.
$$
As a special case, (40) gives that
$$ x\,J_{0}(x)  = J_1(x) +  x\,\frac{dJ_1 (x)}{dx}  
\tag{50}.
$$
As a special case, (30) and (10) give that
$$
 \frac{dJ_0 (x)}{dx} = -  J_{ 1}(x) .
\tag{60}
$$
In addition, adding (20) and (30), dividing by, mutliplying by $x^n$ and re-arranging produces the following:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^n\,J_{n}(x)\right] = x^n\,J_{n-1}(x).
\tag{70}
$$
As a special case, (70) gives that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[x \,J_{1}(x)\right] = x \,J_{0}(x).
\tag{80}
$$

Using (80) reveals that
$$
\int_{ar = 0}^a \frac{d}{d(a\,r)}\left[(a\,r) \,J_{1}((a\,r))\right] \,d(ar)= \int_{ar = 0}^a (a\,r) \,J_{0}(a\,r) \,d(ar).
$$
Or,
$$
  \left[(a\,r) \,J_{1}((a\,r))\right]_{ar = 0}^a = a^2\int_{r = 0}^1  r  \,J_{0}(a\,r) \,dr.
$$
Or,
$$
  \int_{r = 0}^1  r  \,J_{0}(a\,r) \,dr=   \frac{1}{a}   \,J_{1}((a ))  .
$$
Setting $a = \alpha_i$ recovers the nomenclature of OP's question.

As given in a lengthy derivation in [1], the normalization integral may be written as
$$
\int_0^a \left[J_nu\left(\alpha_{\nu,m}\frac{\rho}{a}\right)\right]^2 \,\rho\,d\rho = \frac{a^2}{2}\left[J_{\nu+1}(\alpha_{\nu,m})\right]^2.
$$
The interested reader may see how the authors [1] explain how to derive this.

[1] Arfken and Weber, *Mathematical Methods for Physicists*, 5th Edition, 671-3, 688-9.

[2] [Verification: Eigenfunction expansion using products of bessel and spherical harmonics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4790195/verification-eigenfunction-expansion-using-products-of-bessel-and-spherical-har)