# Verification: Eigenfunction expansion using products of bessel and spherical harmonics

Tags: mathematical-physics, orthogonality, bessel-functions, sturm-liouville, spherical-harmonics

**Preface**

This is a *can you please check my work* post. Maybe these are frowned upon. However, I have been working on this for a couple of days now. I can use some help.

**Context**

I am solving a physics problem on the subject of spherical multipole radiation. The solutions are of interest harmonic and tend to satisfy the Helmholtz equation in spherical coordinates.

As part of this problem I obtain the equation
$$
 f_{\pm}(\mathbf{r},t)
=
 \exp{\left(\pm i  
 k\,r  
 \right)}
\,
 \cos(\theta). \tag{1}
$$
I wish to expand (1) using elementary solutions of the Helmholtz equation. Some scant background can be found in [1].

I write
\begin{align}
 \exp{\left(\pm i  
 k\,r 
 \right)}
\,
 \cos(\theta) = \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell \left[A_{\ell_\pm}\,j_{\ell}{(k\,r)} + B_{\ell_\pm}\,n_{\ell}{(k\,r)} \right]Y_{\ell}^m(\theta,\varphi),\qquad \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $j_\ell$  and $n_\ell$ are spherical Bessel functions of the first and second kind, respectively, and $Y_\ell^m$ is are the  spherical harmonics.

**Question**

How can I determine the values of the coefficients?

**My attempt**

Well, I can rewrite the left-hand side in terms of one, and only one, spherical harmonic.   I find that
\begin{align}
 \exp{\left(\pm i  
k\,r 
 \right)}
\,
2\,\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}\, Y_1^0(\theta,\varphi)   = \sum_\ell^\infty\sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell \left[A_{\ell_\pm}\,j_{\ell}{(k\,r)} + B_{\ell_\pm}\,n_{\ell}{(k\,r)} \right]Y_{\ell}^m(\theta,\varphi),
\end{align}
Thus, the problem is substantially simplified:
\begin{align}
 \exp{\left(\pm i  
k\,r 
 \right)}
\,
2\,\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}  =    A_{1_\pm}\,j_{1}{(k\,r)} + B_{1_\pm}\,n_{1}{(k\,r)}  .
\end{align}

Moving on, I turn to Sturm-Liouvill theory. The Bessel's have an orthogonality condition and a normaliztion condition. From [2], I know that
``the spherical Bessel functions the orthogonality relation is:
$$\int_0^\infty x^2 j_\alpha(ux) j_\alpha(vx) \,dx = \frac{\pi}{2u^2} \delta(u - v)$$
for $\alpha > −1$''.
This is relevant to my solution. I write
\begin{align}
A_{1_\pm}\,\frac{\pi}{2\,k^2} \delta(k - k^\prime)
 = 
2\,\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}  \, \int_{0}^\infty r^2 
 \exp{\left(\pm i  
 k\,r  
 \right)}
\,
j_{1}{(k^\prime\,r)} \,dr,
\\
B_{1_\pm}\,\frac{\pi}{2\,k^2} \delta(k - k^\prime)
 = 
2\,\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}  \, \int_{0}^\infty r^2 
 \exp{\left(\pm i  
 k\,r 
 \right)}
\,
n_{1}{(k^\prime\,r)} \,dr
.
\end{align}
This seems all right to me. Next, I am aware that these particular spherical Bessel functions can be rewritten in terms of circular functions.  I find that
\begin{align}
A_{1_\pm}\,\frac{\pi}{2\,k^2} \delta(k - k^\prime)
&= 
2\,\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}  \, \int_{0}^\infty r^2 
 \exp{\left(\pm i  
 k\,r 
 \right)}
\,
\left[
\frac{\sin(k^\prime\,r)}{(k^\prime\,r)^2}
-
\frac{\cos(k^\prime\,r)}{(k^\prime\,r) }
\right]
\,dr,
\\
B_{1_\pm}\,\frac{\pi}{2\,k^2} \delta(k - k^\prime)
 &= 
2\,\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}  \, \int_{0}^\infty r^2 
 \exp{\left(\pm i  
k\,r 
 \right)}
\,
\left[
- \frac{\cos(k^\prime\,r)}{(k^\prime\,r)^2}
-
\frac{\sin(k^\prime\,r)}{(k^\prime\,r) }
\right]
\,dr
.
\end{align}
Upon evaluation, I obtain that
\begin{align}
A_{1_\pm}\,\frac{\pi}{2\,k^2} \delta(k - k^\prime)
&=
\frac{2\,{k^\prime}^3-\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow \infty }{\mathrm{e}}^{\pm i\,r\,k}\,\left(
\left[
r  \, {k^\prime}^2 \left(
{k^\prime}^2
-
 k^2 
\right)
\pm
i\,k\left(
k^2
-
3\, {k^\prime}^2  
\right)
\right]
\sin\left(r\,k^\prime\right)
+
\left[
2\,{k^\prime}^3 
\pm
i\,r\,k\,{k^\prime}\left(
{k^\prime}^2
-
\,k^2 
\right)
\right]
\cos\left(r\,k^\prime\right) 
\right)
}{{k^\prime}^2\,{\left(k^2-{k^\prime}^2\right)}^2}
\\
B_{1_\pm}\,\frac{\pi}{2\,k^2} \delta(k - k^\prime)
&=
 \frac{
\pm i\,k\left(3\,{k^\prime }^2 -k^2 \right)
-   \lim\limits_{r\rightarrow \infty }{e}^{\pm i\,k\,r}\,\left(
\left[
2\,{k^\prime }^3
\pm
i\,k\,k^\prime\,r
\left(
 {k^\prime }^2 
-
 k^2 
\right)
\right]
\sin\left(k^\prime \,r\right)
+
\left[
{k^\prime }^2\,r \left(
k^2 
-
{k^\prime }^2 
\right)
\pm
i\,k
\left(
3 \,{k^\prime }^2 
-
 k^2
 \right)
\right]
\cos\left(k^\prime \,r\right) 
\right)
}
{
{k^\prime }^2\,{\left(k^2-{k^\prime }^2\right)}^2}
\end{align}

Geez! Assuming this is even correct, it appears that I have two options. I am not sure what to do first. So, first I will take the limit as $r\to\infty$ and then integrate over $k^\prime$. Second, I will do it the other way around.

*Option 1*
\begin{align}
A_{1_\pm}\,\frac{\pi}{2\,k^2} \delta(k - k^\prime)
&=
\frac{2\,{k^\prime}^2-\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow \infty }
\pm
i\,
e^{\pm i\,r\,k}\,r\,\left(
{k^\prime}^2
-
\,k^2 
\right)
\,\left(
k
\,
\cos\left(r\,k^\prime\right) 
\mp i\,
k^\prime
\,
\sin\left(r\,k^\prime\right)
\right)
}{{k^\prime} \,{\left(k^2-{k^\prime}^2\right)}^2}
\\
B_{1_\pm}\,\frac{\pi}{2\,k^2} \delta(k - k^\prime)
&=
 \frac{
\pm i\,k\left(3\,{k^\prime }^2 -k^2 \right)
-   \lim\limits_{r\rightarrow \infty } {k^\prime }\,r 
\left(
k^2 
-
{k^\prime }^2 
\right)
 {e}^{\pm i\,k\,r}\,\left(
k^\prime 
\,
\cos\left(k^\prime \,r\right) 
\pm
i\,k  
\sin\left(k^\prime \,r\right)
\right)
}
{
{k^\prime }^2\,{\left(k^2-{k^\prime }^2\right)}^2}
\end{align}

Next, I integrate
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty A_{1_\pm}\,\frac{\pi}{2\,k^2} \delta(k - k^\prime) \,dk^\prime
&=
\int_0^\infty  
\frac{2\,{k^\prime}^2-\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow \infty }
\pm
i\,
e^{\pm i\,r\,k}\,r\,\left(
{k^\prime}^2
-
\,k^2 
\right)
\,\left(
k
\,
\cos\left(r\,k^\prime\right) 
\mp i\,
k^\prime
\,
\sin\left(r\,k^\prime\right)
\right)
}{{k^\prime} \,{\left(k^2-{k^\prime}^2\right)}^2}
\,dk^\prime
\\
\int_0^\infty  
B_{1_\pm}\,\frac{\pi}{2\,k^2} \delta(k - k^\prime)
\,dk^\prime
&=
\int_0^\infty  
 \frac{
\pm i\,k\left(3\,{k^\prime }^2 -k^2 \right)
-   \lim\limits_{r\rightarrow \infty } {k^\prime }\,r 
\left(
k^2 
-
{k^\prime }^2 
\right)
 {e}^{\pm i\,k\,r}\,\left(
k^\prime 
\,
\cos\left(k^\prime \,r\right) 
\pm
i\,k  
\sin\left(k^\prime \,r\right)
\right)
}
{
{k^\prime }^2\,{\left(k^2-{k^\prime }^2\right)}^2}
\,dk^\prime.
\end{align}
I obtain
\begin{align}
 A_{1_\pm} 
&=
0
\\
B_{1_\pm} 
&=
0.
\end{align}

Ugh! This can not be right.

**Bibliography**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane-wave_expansion

Comment: Do you mean $$f_{\pm}(r, t) = \exp(\pm i k r \cos \theta)$$ i.e the [Jacobi expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion)? Or are you really looking for something closer to a [plane wave expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane-wave_expansion)?

Comment: I do not mean $\exp{\left(\pm k\,r\,\cos\theta}$. I mean a plane wave expansion. I want to find the expansion coefficients $A_\pm$ and $B_pm$ given in my Equation 2 above